# Открытие доступа к сайту через интернет OpenServerPanel

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер, openserver, роутер, порты

Суть: хочу открыть доступ к сайту с любого устройства через интернет, используется OpenServerPanel

- Сразу скажу, ip **белый** и **статический**, это точно, проверял на игровом tcp сервере, на него можно было подключаться через интернет
- На роутере **сделал проброс портов**
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- В настройках OSP в разделе Алиасы связал внешний ip с конечным доменом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- В разделе Сервер указал все доступные ip
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При подключении через локальную сеть все работает (указываю внешний ip), при подключении через интернет сайт начинает как-будто пытаться загрузиться, секунд через 7 появляется следующая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сменить порт с 80 на другой, так же нужно сменить http порт в openserver на новый. Чтобы зайти на сайт введите ваш IP, двоеточие и порт. Пример: 255.255.255.255:800.

Comment: помогло, спасибо, а с чем  эта проблема  может быть связана?

Comment: Это надо узнавать у вашего провайдера

Comment: блокирует подключения на 80 порт?

Comment: У tp link вроде есть подключение удалённо. Возможно в этом дело